# Installing missing project assembly without VS or Nuget

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I am getting following error in an ASP.NET application.
"*Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference*"

I have .NET Framework 4.0 installed on the server, my application is running under 4.0 application pool on development server, as production server.

Development server web.config - (EF section)
*`<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />`*

Development server runtime EF DLL: v4.0.30319

I have selected copy local to TRUE.

Error is straight forward, as it is clear application is looking for EF 6.0.0.0.

However, I am not sure why? Also, how do I install EF 6.0 on server.

Note: Server has only iis, no Visual studio or any other development tool.

Comment: Did you check the project settings to see if you have 4.0 selected.  I think the version of VS you are using is selecting a new version of Net.  Simple change the Net version under project settings.

Answer (score 0):

For server troubleshooting (not sure what version of Window you using), I would suggest you using [Assembly Binding Log View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.100).aspx) and perhaps would give you more information about the dlls/dependency that failed to load at run time.

Comment: I have got Windows 2012 R2, I am not able to find fuslogvw.exe in the system, can you point a specific location?

Comment: do you have VS studio installed in the server ? otherwise you can install the Window SDK and the component is inside.

Comment: No there is no Visual studio installed, I will go for Windows SDK.